# bash check given port range if in use and tell if all in use

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which checks a given port range and see if any of them in use, and choose the one which is not in use;

```sh
starting_port=5550
ending_port=5650

function check_port {
        echo "I'm going to find an open port to use"
        for i in $(seq $starting_port $ending_port); do
                if ! lsof -Pi :$i -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null; then
                        echo "$i not in use, I'm going to choose this one"
                        port_to_use=$i
                fi
        done
}

check_port
```

However, I want to go a little further and check if all ports are in use, return something like;

```sh
echo "I couldn't find a port to use, all given ports are in use"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I guess `lsof` returns with zero even if the port is free. You have to pipe it to `grep` probably. I think it would be just easier for `lsof` and perfomance, to have `lsof` report all ports with `TCP:LISTEN` and after it use a single `grep "5550|5551|...."` to check if the port exists or not.

Comment: It seems to be returning the correct status of the ports if I add an if/else statement to check whether a port in use or not. I did this in the first place to see if `lsof` working fine or not. Am I missing something?

Comment: `netstat --numeric --numeric-ports | grep ':'` and then sort by port, etc..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that command actually returns hundreds of ports, if not thousands, most likely due to the applications I'm running (they're some sort of seeding stuff) so I guess it will be hard to elect them with that command, right?

Comment: Wow. I only had a handful returned and I had quite a bit running. `netstat` looked promising up until that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand from your last comment that you have thousands of ports in use and you want to be able to set some starting port number, and iterate over the port numbers until you find an available `port_to_use`, then you can use `netstat` as outlined above, and with GNU `awk` (e.g. `gawk`) find the first available without much hassle.

For example, calling the `netstat` command as above, and with then with `awk` initially setting your `port_to_use = minimum_port` and filling an array with all the *ports in use* and then using the `END` rule to sort and iterate over the *ports in use* incrementing `port_to_use` by `1` each iteration until *ports in use*, e,g, `(a[i] > port_to_use)` you can locate the first available port.

A short call to `gawk` should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

netstat --numeric --numeric-ports | 
awk -F'[ \t:]*' -v port_to_use=32000 '/[:]/ {
    a[i++] = $5
}
END {
    n = asort (a)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (a[i] == port_to_use)
            port_to_use++
        else
            break;
    print "port to use:", port_to_use
}'
```

Just save it and call it with:

```
$ bash nameyousaveditin
port to use: 32000
```

(or just set the minimum port number and copy/paste it into a terminal without the `#!/bin/bash`)

**Example**

In my case where the ports in use are:

```
36226
36998
38728
46894
49756
52194
54686
...
```

Initially setting `port_to_use=36226` results in:

```
$ bash find_port_to_use
port to use: 36227
```

**Adding an** `end_port`

You can add an `end_port` to limit the number of ports you consider available to the `END` rule. The following will only consider ports from your minimum up to the `end_port`. (you could also rearrange and just add a number to consider, like `150`, and just do the math from the minimum)

```
#!/bin/bash

netstat --numeric --numeric-ports | 
awk -F'[ \t:]*' -v port_to_use=32000 -v end_port=32050 '/[:]/ {
    a[i++] = $5
}
END {
    n = asort (a)
    for (i = 1; i <= n && a[i] <= end_port; i++)
        if (a[i] == port_to_use)
            port_to_use++
        else
            break;
    if (port_to_use > end_port)
        print "no ports available in range"
    else
        print "port to use:", port_to_use
}'
```

The `end_port` is just added as an additional variable at the beginning of the `awk` command and used in the `END` rule.

**Using `netstat --listening**

To have `netstat` report the local `listening` port, add the `--listening` option to the `netstat` command and an additional check to make sure the port is a numeric port and not just `'*'`. Making the changes, you could alter the first part as follows:

```
netstat --numeric --numeric-ports --listening | 
awk -F'[ \t:]*' -v port_to_use=32000 -v end_port=32050 '/[:]/ {
    if ($5 ~ '/[0-9][0-9]*/')
        a[i++] = $5
}
## rest is the same
```

Using it with local ports, it lists my ports in use as:

```
22
25
25
68
123
123
123
123
631
631
2677
5353
51310
```

(which seems closer to the ranges you were looking for)

Give it a shot and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I had but I was dead today. Using a faster command is always better, but you are correct about the subshells. Here is my question. "How are you binding the ports to sockets in your code?" I ask because there should be someway of simply listing the ports you have opened with either `lsof` or `netstat`. Are you just setting up a `struct sockaddr_in` and then calling `bind`?

Comment: Not even a problem! These are 3rd party applications so I don't know the answer to your question. They're listening to TCP, if that helps. And this is what I get if I run `sudo netstat -plnt`; `tcp6       0      0 :::5580                 :::*                    LISTEN` (this is just one example port, it lists hundreds of ports and I'm reading my port range from there)

Comment: The 3rd party apps must be doing something strange in binding the ports to the socket. I set up a couple of server-client processes using the standard `struct sockaddr_in`, setting the port and then calling `bind` to bind the port to the socket and they show up as expected with `netstat --numeric --numeric-ports --listening`. You should `tcp6` are all the ports you are using bound to IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Those applications are both binding IPv4 and IPv6 so there are 2 items in the `netstat -plnt` command for each application. One for `tcp` and another one for `tcp6`. So I've showed you `tcp6` one in my previous message but as I said, there is also a `tcp` version for the same port.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution myself, which was really easier than I thought.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

starting_port=5550
ending_port=5650

function check_port {
    echo "I'm going to find an open port to use"
    for i in $(seq $starting_port $ending_port); do
        if ! lsof -Pi :$i -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null; then
            echo "$i not in use, I'm going to choose this one"
            port_to_use=$i
        elif [ "$i" == "$ending_port" ]; then < I've simply added this part.
            echo "no port to use"
        fi
    done
}

check_port
```

Faster solution using `netstat` instead of `lsof`;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

starting_port=5550
ending_port=5650

for i in $(seq $starting_port $ending_port); do
    if ! [[ $(sudo netstat -plnt | grep ":$i") ]]; then
        echo "$i not in use, I'm going to choose this one"
        port_to_use=$i
        break
    elif [ "$i" == "$ending_port" ]; then
        echo "no ports to use"
    fi
done
```

Comment: For a hundred ports, it's not that critical, but if you are faced with a loop that may iterate thousands or hundreds of thousands of times, be very mindful about calling utilities within the loop (you spawn an additional subshell for every utility call). That is the advantage that the stream editing programs `awk` and `sed` provide. Here, it isn't a big deal, you are only calling `lsof`. (there was one gentlemen yesterday that called 13 utilities and 4 *command substitutions* in each iteration over a million lines -- no wonder it took hours to run..). Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: That's right, it's really slow even for 100 ports. I'll give your script a shot now.